# Return from initializer without initializing all stored properties - Contacts Store

Tags: swiftui, contacts

Code from tutorial, want to access contacts from my app, and using this as base
Need to solve this error to move forward and do not know what additional items needs initialization.  Any help very appreciated.

```
import Contacts

final class ContactsViewModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published
    var contact: [Contact?]
    @Published
    var contacts: [Contact?] = []
    @Published
    var permissionsError: PermissionsError? = .none
    
    init( contact: Contact, contacts: [Contact] , permissionsError: PermissionsError) {
        permissions()
    }.                **<-- Error occurs here -** 
    
    func openSettings() {
        permissionsError = .none
        guard let settingsURL = URL(string: UIApplication.openSettingsURLString) else {return}
        if UIApplication.shared.canOpenURL(settingsURL) { UIApplication.shared.open(settingsURL)}
    }
    func getContacts() {
    Contact.fetchAll { [weak self] result in
        guard let self = self else { return }
        switch result {
            case .success(let fetchedContacts):
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.contacts = fetchedContacts.sorted(by: { $0.lastName < $1.lastName })
            }
            case .failure(let error):
                self.permissionsError = .fetchError(error)
            
        }
    }
}
    func permissions() {
        switch CNContactStore.authorizationStatus(for: .contacts) {
        case.authorized:
            getContacts()
        case .notDetermined, .restricted, .denied :
            CNContactStore().requestAccess(for: .contacts) { [weak self] granted, error in
                switch granted {
                case true: self?.getContacts()
                case false:
                    DispatchQueue.main.async {
                        self?.permissionsError = .userError
                    }
                }
            }
```

Comment: You have to set your properties based on the parameters passed to the initializer. For example: `self.contacts = contacts`

Comment: Added the following and errors went away --```init( contact: Contact, contacts: [Contact] , permissionsError: PermissionsError) {
        self.contacts = contacts
        self.contact = [contact]
        self.permissionsError = permissionsError
        permissions()
    }```caused errors in ContentView ```struct ContentView: View {
    @StateObject
    private var contactsVM = ContactsViewModel().  <--- ERROR HERE
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            List {
                ForEach(contactsVM.contacts) { contact in. <=== ERROR HERE
               ...
```

Comment: Error 1 -Missing arguments for parameters 'contact', 'contacts', 'permissionsError' in call. Error2 - Unable to infer type of a closure parameter '_' in the current context - might could fix but worried I'm chasing my tail.

Comment: If you have a initializer with parameters, you have to send parameters to it. Might be a good time to brush up on Swift basics in something like Apple’s Swift book or the Hacking with Swift series, since this is a pretty fundamental programming concept.

Comment: Thanks, I get that and could continue, but since the tutorial "worked", it didn't seem like going down the path of just fixing things that keep breaking was good option.  I had read in early research that a change happened in one a swiftui version that broke the code and thought perhaps there was something simple to fix it.  Will just go with a different example for accessing contacts for my app.

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? Following the same tutorial and it's not working (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=C1qri8D2Bo8)